# Intel Galileo - greenlet.h:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, gcc, greenlets, intel-galileo

I'm running Linux dev-tools image (link at the end) on my intel galileo. I tried to install greenlet but I got an error stating `python.h` no such file.

```
root@clanton:/media/realroot/greenlet-0.4.2# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
creating /tmp/tmpuKbWhk/tmp
creating /tmp/tmpuKbWhk/tmp/tmpuKbWhk
i586-poky-linux-uclibc-gcc -m32 -march=i586 -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -fno-tree-dominator-opts -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/tmpuKbWhk/simple.c -o /tmp/tmpuKbWhk/tmp/tmpuKbWhk/simple.o
/tmp/tmpuKbWhk/simple.c:1:6: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
building 'greenlet' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-i586-2.7
i586-poky-linux-uclibc-gcc -m32 -march=i586 -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -fno-tree-dominator-opts -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-i586-2.7/greenlet.o
```

In file included from greenlet.c:5:0:

```
greenlet.h:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i586-poky-linux-uclibc-gcc' failed with exit status 1**
```

**I know there are many posts with the same python.h error but my problem is the Linux image I have can't run sudo or apt commands**

I need to setup python-dev environment onto my Linux image running on Galileo board. 
Link to the Linux dev-tools image I'm using is here below.
http://telekinect.media.mit.edu/galileo/image-devtools-1.0.1-2.tar.bz2

p.s. it has gcc and python2.7 already.

Comment: do you have `python-dev` installed? Try  `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: Thanks padraic. Much appreciated.

the problem is the linux image i'm running dosen't recognize the sudo apt-get commands. thats the problem. I researched over the net but all i could get is the same statements which are unrecognized.
is there any other way around to install python-dev?

Comment: you could install python from soure, I think the python dev headers gets installed by default.